# Strange asymmetry when plotting identical exponents?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot

Instead of the expected symmetric shape:

[image]

what I get from this code:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

   \newcommand{\vandbarrierdel}[1]{ 
      \node at (#1, 1.9) {\scriptsize $U_0$};
   }

   \begin{tikzpicture}
       \fill[gray]  
           (0, 0) rectangle (2.8, 4)
           (3.2, 0) rectangle (6, 4)
           (2.8, 0) rectangle (3.2, 2);

       \vandbarrierdel{2.6}

       \draw[red, thick] plot[variable = \x, domain = -3 : 0, smooth] ({\x + 3}, {2.0 + exp{\x*2}});
       \draw[red, thick] plot[variable = \x, domain =  0 : 3, smooth] ({\x + 3}, {2.0 + exp{-\x*2}});

       \node[anchor = north] at (3, 4.5) {\scriptsize $0$};
       \node[anchor = north] at (6, 4.5) {\scriptsize $x$};
       \draw[<->] (0, 4) to (6, 4);
       \draw[-] (2.8, 2) to (2.8, 4);
       \draw[-] (3.2, 2) to (3.2, 4);
       \draw[-] (2.8, 2) to (3.2, 2);
   \end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

is:

[image]

Why is that the case? How to correct it so that it is symmetric?

---

Comment: Off-topic: to get a line without jumps you can use a piece-wise function: `\draw[red, thick] plot[variable = \x, domain = -3 : 3, samples=61] (\x + 3,{2 +(\x < 0) * (exp(\x*2)) + (\x >= 0) * (exp(-\x*2))});` Note that you should _not_ use smooth for this, because it will significantly deform the tip.

Comment: @Max Thanks but it is meant to have a first derivative discontinuity at x = 0.

Comment: Nevermind me then, just passing by :)

Comment: Just following up on @Max's idea: it indeed looks a bit nicer IMHO if you do `\draw[red, thick] 
    plot[variable = \x, domain = -3 : 0, smooth] ({\x + 3}, {2.0 + exp(\x*2)})
    -- plot[variable = \x, domain =  0 : 3, smooth] ({\x + 3}, {2.0 + exp(-\x*2)});` since then there is only one path, whose slope jumps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is just a syntax error. You forgot the brackets around the argument of `exp`.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

   \newcommand{\vandbarrierdel}[1]{ 
      \node at (#1, 1.9) {\scriptsize $U_0$};
   }

   \begin{tikzpicture}
       \fill[gray]  
           (0, 0) rectangle (2.8, 4)
           (3.2, 0) rectangle (6, 4)
           (2.8, 0) rectangle (3.2, 2);

       \vandbarrierdel{2.6}

       \draw[red, thick] plot[variable = \x, domain = -3 : 0, smooth] ({\x + 3}, {2.0 + exp(\x*2)});
       \draw[red, thick] plot[variable = \x, domain =  0 : 3, smooth] ({\x + 3}, {2.0 + exp(-\x*2)});

       \node[anchor = north] at (3, 4.5) {\scriptsize $0$};
       \node[anchor = north] at (6, 4.5) {\scriptsize $x$};
       \draw[<->] (0, 4) to (6, 4);
       \draw[-] (2.8, 2) to (2.8, 4);
       \draw[-] (3.2, 2) to (3.2, 4);
       \draw[-] (2.8, 2) to (3.2, 2);
   \end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]